# In how many ways can people get out of the elevator?

Tags: combinatorics

My specific problem states that there are 8 people inside the elevator and there are 5 floors. In how many ways can they get out if there's a requirement that at least one person leaves at each floor?

The answer is 126000 and I can't get anywhere near it. I do not know if this is the correct answer.

I've tried solving the $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 3$ and then playing with the numbers but didn't get anywhere close.

I am not sure if the order by which people exit the elevator matters as nothing in the problem states that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers are small, so we can do it by cases. Maybe (Case 1) $4$ people get off at one floor, with the rest $1$ each.  Or maybe (Case 2) it is $3$ on one floor, $2$ another, and the rest $1$ each. Or maybe (Case 3) it is $2$. $2$, $2$ with the rest $1$ each.

I will do Case 1, and Case 3 because it is slightly tricky. You can do Case 2.

Case 1: The floor at which the $4$ people get off can be chosen in $\binom{5}{1}$ ways. For each such choice, the actual people who get off there can be chosen in $\binom{8}{4}$ ways. Once this is done, there are $4$ floors and $4$ people. That gives $4!$ arrangements. So there are
$$\binom{5}{1}\binom{8}{4}4!$$
Case 1 possibilities.

Case 3: We do this one because it is tricky, one can get the wrong answer. The special floors at which the pairs get off can be chosen in $\binom{5}{3}$ ways. Once these have been chosen, the $2$ people who get off at the *lowest* special floor can be chosen in $\binom{8}{2}$ ways and then the $2$ people who get off at the next special floor can be chosen in $\binom{6}{2}$ ways, and then the $2$ people who get off at the highest chosen floor can be selected in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways. Finally, the two singles can be assigned to the remaining floors in $2!$ ways. Multiply.

Comment: I think the $\binom{5}{2}$ in your case 3 is a typo, right? (should be $\binom{5}{3}$)

Comment: I had corrected it while editing. Luckily, it doesn't even matter, since $\binom{5}{3}=\binom{5}{2}$.

Comment: Good point. :).         .

Comment: @AndréNicolas In your case 3, can't we do: first floor choose in $\binom{5}{1}$, then some people get off. Second floor choose in $\binom{4}{1}$ then some people get off. And continue till last floor. Will this be an incorrect approach (and why?) Thank you!

Comment: @AndréNicolas Also, when we have all the case values; do we add or multiply them?

Comment: @GaurangTandon: As to your second question, we add.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you. And first question?

Comment: @GaurangTandon: About the first question, I do not see how this counts the Case (iii) patterns. There are other fancier ways to tackle the problem, please see the Wikipedia article on Stirling numbers of the second kind.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you. I meant that we choose one floor in $\binom{5}{1}$ where $\binom{8}{2}$ people get off. Then another floor in $\binom{4}{1}$ where $\binom{6}{2}$ people get off. Then another floor chosen in $\binom{3}{1}$ where $\binom{4}{2}$ people get off. And then the last two persons have $2!$ ways. I know yours is a shorter and better approach, but I want to know whether this method is correct, or not? If not, then why? Thank you!

Comment: @GaurangTandon: In the above comment, there is an overcount by a factor of $3!$. Very similar to the common overcount in finding the number of two-pair poker hands. The problem is that among the $\binom{5}{1}$ choices we have Floor 2, and among the $\binom{4}{1}$ we have Floor $6$. But among the $\binom{5}{1}$ we have Floor 6, and among the $\binom{4}{1}$ we have Floor 2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19239/discussion-between-gaurang-tandon-and-andre-nicolas).

Comment: After a couple of negative experiences, I stopped using chat.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 3$ only takes into account the number of people who exit onto each floor, not who the people are. What you want is to partition the set of 8 people into 5 nonempty labelled subsets. That is, you want the number of surjective functions from $\{1,\dots,8\}$ to $\{1,\dots,5\}$. See [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Comment: I do agree that the above equation doesn't take the people as individuals but I realized that I could "paint" them but couldn't do it properly.
Stirling numbers formula works for unlabeled subsets but "painting" the subsets $n \brace {k} $$\cdot 5!$ gives me the desired 126000.

Thanks for the hint!